# SQL statement's placeholders that is not replaced leads to "Cannot update '@columnName'; field not updateable"

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

I'm writing some code updating database with a SQL statement that has some placeholders . But it doesn't seem to update these placeholders.

I got the following error:

`Cannot update '@columnName'; field not updateable`

Here is the method:

```
    public void updateDoctorTableField(string columnName, string newValue, string vendorNumber) {
        sqlStatement = "update Doctor set @columnName = @newValue where `VENDOR #` = @vendorNumber;";
        try {
            _command = new OleDbCommand(sqlStatement, _connection);
            _command.Parameters.Add("@columnName", OleDbType.WChar).Value = columnName;
            _command.Parameters.Add("@newValue", OleDbType.WChar).Value = newValue;
            _command.Parameters.Add("@vendorNumber", OleDbType.WChar).Value = vendorNumber;

            _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            processExeption(ex);
        } finally {
            _connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all parts of the query are parameterisable.

You can't parametrise the name of the column. This needs to be specified explicitly in your query text.

If this is sent via user input you need to take care against SQL Injection. In fact in any event it would be best to check it against a whitelist of known valid column names.

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply. It works. So the reason why the field name can't be parameterisable is to check it against a whitelist?

Comment: @draw - No, that isn't the reason itself. The language grammar only allows parameters in certain specified places. The parameterisation isn't just a kind of string interpolation that you can use to replace arbitrary parts of the query with. But given that restriction whenever you dynamically assemble a query at run time via string concatenation it is best to consider sensible precautions against SQL injection.

Comment: Ok, I see. So what's the reason that Microsoft guys don't prevent field name input from SQL injection in a parameterisation fashion?

Comment: Don't know. You'd have to ask them that! I guess it would be complex to implement and wouldn't really fit in very well with the current plan compilation mechanism or usage of parameters and as the easy enough work around is dynamic SQL other things have much clearer benefit.

Comment: [This connect item is Closed - Won't Fix](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/498060/) so I wouldn't expect this any time soon!

Answer (score 1):

The reason the language does not allow for parameters for things like table names, column names and such is exactly the same reason why your C# program does not allow for substitution of variables in the code. Basically your question can be rephrased like this in a C# program:

```
class MyClass
{
    int x;
    float y;
    string z;


    void DoSomething(string variableName)
    {
        this.@variable = ...
    }
}

MyCLass my = new MyClass();
my.DoSomething("x"); // expect this to manuipulate my.x
my.DoSomething("y"); // expect this to manuipulate my.y
my.DoSomething("z"); // expect this to manuipulate my.z
```

This obviously won't compile, because the compiler cannot generate the code. Same for T-SQL: the compiler cannot generate the code to locate the column `"@columnName"` in your case. And just as in C# you would use reflection to do this kind of tricks, in T-SQL you would use dynamic SQL to achieve the same.

You can (and should) use the [`QUOTENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) function when building your dynamic SQL to guard against SQL injection.